# Jenkins links point to http instead of HTTPS resulting in login screen infinite loop

Tags: apache, jenkins, proxy

For some reason Jenkins is redirecting the login screen back to the login screen when a successful login is made. See the attached packet trace. If I give the expected URL using https instead of HTTP all the pages load fine.

I have Jenkins configured behind a reverse proxy using apache. The proxy redirects traffic at /jenkins to :8080/jenkins. The base url is set to https://domain/jenkins and the jenkins --prefix parameter is set to /jenkins. I appreciate any help!

[image: Packet Trace]

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. There was an error in my rewrite in the http virtualhost in apache. With the extra slash removed Jenkins no works but it is still sending http packets into the proxy server which then need to be rewritten to https instead of just posting all https links. Works but there is still and issue with Jenkins unfortunately.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}**/**$1 [R,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

The slash in the Rewrite rule was causing the URL to be rewritten slightly wrong. Most web application I've used previously can tolerate this error evidently as I have only encountered this problem 3 years after initially setting up the server.